# Sort a dictionary array when the key is given as the parameter

Tags: swift, nsarray

I'm working in a project in swift3 and I have an NSArray named "details" that contains NSDictionary Objects. My requirement is to sort this NSArray If a "key" is passed as the parameter (eg:- name, lastName, age). My NSArray looks like bellow.

```
(
 {name:"John";
  lastName :"bow";
  age: "26"; 
 },
 {
  name:"paul";
  lastName :"law";
  age: "19";
  }

)
```

how can I achieve this ??

Comment: you need to sort array ?

Comment: objective-c or swift? you tagged both. This sounds like it could be homework

Comment: Swift 3 would be fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
NSSortDescriptor * sortDescriptors = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES]; // change your key here
NSArray * arrSortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor];
NSArray * sortedArray = [yourArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:arrSortDescriptors];
NSLog(@"sortedArray %@",sortedArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `sort`:

```
var dicts = [["name":"b"], ["name":"a"], ["name":"z"], ["name":"f"]]
dicts.sort { $0["name"]! < $1["name"]! }
print(dicts)
```

Prints `[["name": "a"], ["name": "b"], ["name": "f"], ["name": "z"]]`